# Varying Electric Field at high frequencies

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Is it true that varying electric fields create varying magnetic fields only for higher frequencies? Why is this so? Correct me if I am wrong about this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that varying electric fields create varying magnetic fields **only** for higher frequencies?

No, it's not true **only** for high frequencies. It's true for **any** frequency and it follows from [Ampere's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law), which states that a change in the electric field, generates a corresponding magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Varying electric fields create varying magnetic fields regardless of frequency. However, if the fields are small and/or they vary slowly, the effect is weak.

Answer (score 0):

The laws of electromagnetism in vacuum are embodied by [Maxwell's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations):
$$\nabla \cdot {\bf E} = \rho / \epsilon_0, \ \nabla\cdot {\bf B} =0. $$
$$  \nabla \times {\bf E} =-\frac{\partial {\bf B}}{\partial t}, \ \nabla \times {\bf B} = \mu_0 ( {\bf J} + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial {\bf E}}{\partial t}). $$
In these equations $\rho$ is the charge density and ${\bf J}$ is the current density. The firsry of second two set of equatins show that if the magnetic field varies in time there is an associated magnetic field, while the second shows that if the electric field that varies in time then there is an associated magnetic field.

Another way to see this is via Jefimenko’s equations, see the [answer to this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/463014/can-a-magnetic-field-be-induced-without-an-electric-field/463077#463077).